# wget command in linux for downloading, But I dont want server to know, I downloaded something

Tags: linux, download, wget, server

I would like to know how to download data from server without knowing the server, or server must not contain any log of my downloading, Is there any way ??

Please Help.

Comment: No. You have to know what to download for case one, and you send a request to the server, how else would it know to send a file back?

Comment: Hi, I know what to download, but server must not keep my record of downloading, using wget command

Comment: That doesn't make sense,  you don't control the server. Why are you afraid of it logging you downloaded something?

Comment: Hi James, I am not afraid, but I want to know if i use wget command dor download file, will there be log of the files i downloaded, can i bypass that.

Comment: No,  you cannot control the behavior of the responding Web server.

Comment: Neither wget, nor any other tool, has any control over what the server logs or does not log. Additionally, you must understand that the computer you're running wget on is not going to be directly connected to the server. This means that every computer or router between these two, through which the file is transmitted, is capable of fully logging what you downloaded. That's how the Internet works, and has always worked. You are being closely monitored everywhere. Be afraid, be very very afraid.

Answer (score 2):

In linux OR in any of the system, if you want to download something from server, you send a request to the server and the server sends some response back. Now,obviously every server at least keeps a log of what all actions are being implemented and what all responses are being generated. At the very minimal, all user history will be flushed at server in minimal server but,even then there is a possible chance that it'd keep a generated log of it's clients actions,although it depends more on the server ...

So, to be more clear, ***something like the data/log will be stored at the server about the downloading process SO THAT it keeps a track on your download and better serves you as a client.***

There is nothing so `wget` command specific about it. From the `linux.about.com`'s page entry about wget,

> wget is a free utility for non-interactive download of files from the
>   Web. It supports HTTP, HTTPS, and FTP protocols, as well as retrieval
>   through HTTP proxies.
>
> wget is non-interactive, meaning that it can work in the background,
>   while the user is not logged on. This allows you to start a retrieval
>   and disconnect from the system, letting wget finish the work. By
>   contrast, most of the Web browsers require constant user's presence,
>   which can be a great hindrance when transferring a lot of data.
>
> wget can follow links in HTML pages and create local versions of
>   remote web sites, fully recreating the directory structure of the
>   original site. This is sometimes referred to as ``recursive
>   downloading.'' While doing that, wget respects the Robot Exclusion
>   Standard (/robots.txt). wget can be instructed to convert the links in
>   downloaded HTML files to the local files for offline viewing.